# How can I change and forward a specific url to a modified url with Violentmonkey (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recaptcha, tampermonkey

First of all, I want to describe my issue:

I can not download Google Recaptcha audio files due to Recaptcha gives wrong url. Here is the explaination:

Wrong url:

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload/audio.mp3*

Correct url:

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload*

Wrong url returns error 404; but the corrent url triggers audio file download.

So, in order to forward the wrong url to the correct one, I have written JavaScript codes like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Google Audio Recaptcha Linki Düzeltici
// @description     Google'ın audio recaptcha linklerini düzelterek indirilebilir olmasını sağlar.
// @namespace       cagataykaya55@hotmail.com
// @version         1.0.0
// @author          Çağatay KAYA
// @license         GNU/GPL
// @released        2021-01-31
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// @match           https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload/audio.mp3*
// @run-at          document-start
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
var eskiRecaptchaLinki = queryString.parse(location.search);
location.href = eskiRecaptchaLinki.replace('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload/audio.mp3', 
'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload');
})();
```

But url forwarding is not working and I still get error 404. How do I fix this?

Comment: URLs that initiate a download can't be intercepted in Violentmonkey, I guess. In Tampermonkey you can probably use [@webRequest](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/397) rules. Or just install an extension that allows custom URL redirection.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok, I have fixed this issue with a Chrome addon. Thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with a Chrome addon.

[In order to download the mentioned addon, click this text.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/ocgpenflpmgnfapjedencafcfakcekcd/related)